# SDK cannot be found in visual studio 2019

Tags: .net, .net-core, sdk, visual-studio-2019

The project file cannot be opened by the project system, because it is missing some critical imports or the referenced SDK cannot be found.

Detailed Information:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the latest SDK 5.0 installed.

If it's not, follow this url:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0